# Spatial Audio Render

Tags: audio

How can I export B Format ambisonic audio in a render. Blender uses OpenAL, which does allow for First Order Ambisonic (4 mono channels, WXYZ) rendering. My goal is to create a stereoscopic, 360 degree video with spatial audio (audio field rotates with head).

---

Here are the documentation links regarding audio in Blender (many of them just say TODO):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/audio/introduction.html

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html#prefs-system-sound

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/properties.html#data-scenes-audio

---

I assume that the *4 Channels* format found in the scene properties context has much to do with spatial audio. Can someone elaborate on these options?

[image]

Demo .blend file to play with (you'll need to supply your own audio):

[image]

[image]

Comment: A very similar question has also been asked [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66275/can-i-render-ambisonic-b-format-audio). (Also upvoted, but without even a comment...)

Answer (score 6):

Can use the [mixdown operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.sound.html#bpy.ops.sound.mixdown) to create an "audio render" of the scene.

Mixdown is next to the render animation button in the latest versions of Blender (There once was a mixdown button on the audio panel)

Otherwise go to the  python console and type in

```
bpy.ops.sound.mixdown('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

to call the operator as if a button was pressed.

[image]

Select a format that allows for the channels, wav is pretty foolproof.

I just added a simple mono wav file to your test file and selected basic old stereo.  Below is the result viewed in audacity.  Starts in left ear, moves to right as it rotates.

[image]

If I choose 4 channels I get a 4 channel wav file.

[image]

Which appears to be  Quadraphonic ears at (facing north) NE, SE, SW, and NW.  (Or speakers at Left Front, Right F, L Rear and RR) rather than [W, X, Y, Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambisonics#Panning_a_source)

Comment: Mixdown is next to the render animation button in the latest versions of Blender...

Comment: Does this mean that 4 track export of discreet audio (no bleeding of sound to other channels) must only be saved from 3D spatialized view via speakers? The VSE also allows 4 types of panning (-2,-1,+1,+2) per piece of media, but they end up mixed.