# Can I render ambisonic b-Format audio?

Tags: rendering, audio

Im looking for a way to render spatialized sound to 1st order ambisonic b-format. I assumed the 4ch option in scene audio settings was the key. But that just seems to render a quad speaker setup?

The 3d sound works ok at runtime in blender, and seems ok when rendered in stereo. But I need the soundfield "rotate-able" in video player for VR experiences.

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73139/28015)

Answer (score 0):

For VR, it makes no difference in which format your multichannel sound is stored, as long as the interpretation of the directional information is done correctly (which again depends on the application).

Both variants (4CH and Ambisonic) contain the information about which direction a sound comes from. They just use a different description of the directional information.
With [Quadraphonic sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadraphonic_sound), the sound comes from four fixed positions, and with the [Ambisonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambisonics) format, the directional information results from an intersection of the W/X/Y/Z axes.

With sound over stereo headphones (which is common in VR), these sound sources are then remixed, depending on the viewing direction.

But if you really insist on a "real" Ambisonic format, you can always convert the four-channel sound into an Ambisonic format yourself.

However, this is definitely not the job of Blender, but of professional audio tools (hardware/software).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same needs, unfortunately I cannot find an easy solution.
The best alternatives I have fund until now are:

1. render audio from Blender in 4 channels as described here:
   [Spatial Audio Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57883/spatial-audio-render)
   but this is not ambisonic, you have to reprocess audio tracks in a DAW like Ardour as seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzg6bKAdu2A
2. render audio from Blender in 5.1 (not ambisonic) and then reprocess with a DAW like Reaper as described here: [Render in 3D audio for YouTube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118564/render-in-3d-audio-for-youtube/139874#139874)

I'm not familiar with DAWs and I'm experimenting with the first solution, but I'm encountering various difficulties, mainly because I can't find documentation explaining how to proceed. Furthermore, following the first path, I think you can manually "direct" the audio but I didn't understand if you can direct the source automatically. Let me explain: if I have a moving Speaker in Blender, the source moves during the animation, but with the first method I only saw how to place the source manually in a fixed point. Maybe there is a way but I'm not understanding how.

I suppose I'll give a try to the second method in the next days when I'll have time.