# Render in 3D audio for YouTube

Tags: audio, panoramic

I'm trying to render 3D audio so that when you turn the view on YouTube, the audio will change depending on what direction you are looking in. Please note that when I say this, I mean VR video and audio.

The Spatial Media Metadata injector [(found here)](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/releases) only supports ambiX ACN/SN3D format audio, and I'd like to find out how to get those file types in Blender. I have 5 speakers, none moving, all playing different ambient sounds (birds, water flowing).

[image: Speakers]
[image: Audio Panel]
[image: Injector]

Software Available:

- Windows 10
- Windows 7
- Mac OS 10.14
- Blender
- Audacity
- iMovie
- GarageBand
- PowerDirector 12
- AnyVideoConverter
- VLC Media Player
- FL Studio

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v_wanFvQlY&list=LLRqgm74ToIt3wbPBwiXwW1Q&index=38&t=0s

Comment: @LeoNas Sorry, that's for a non-spherical video. I need audio that will move when your head does.

Comment: @CStafford-14 During audio rendering, first select audio container (e.g. mp3) then select the "split channel" option which will generate six tracks for 5:1 setup. Then you can mix these tracks with the help of some Ambisonics plugin to generate ACN/SN3D format, here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcUwiYwgBHw, https://www.brucewiggins.co.uk/?p=666

Comment: @3DSinghVFX Can you not post it as an answer? I was able to make it work, thanks to you. https://youtu.be/xq06CgPveM8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather simple as to do this, also, for free :)

Thanks to @3DSinghVFX for the answer in a comment.

> During audio rendering, first select audio container (e.g. mp3) then select the "split channel" option which will generate six tracks for 5:1 setup. Then you can mix these tracks with the help of some Ambisonics plugin to generate ACN/SN3D format.

Add all the tracks into a DAW (I'm using Reaper), and enable the [WigAmbiRemap](http://www.brucewiggins.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WigAmbiRemap.zip) JS Effect. Set the `Outgoing Amb Normalisation` to SN3D and `Outgoing Channel Ordering` to ACN. Then render to a file with 4 channels.
[image: Setup]
Then, render the video and "glue" them together with ffmpeg.

Use this in the terminal (CMD or Bash will do, ffmpeg must be installed)

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i video.mov -i ambiX.wav -map 1:a -map 0:v -c:a copy -channel_layout 4.0 -c:v libx264 -b:v 40000k -bufsize 40000k -shortest output.mov
```

You can change the following:

`video.mov` can be a .mov file or image file, and represents the video.
`ambiX.wav` is the 4-channel B360 Ambisonic file.
`output.mov` is the output file.

After that, pop it through the metadata injector (Making sure you check the 1st and 3rd checkbox, 2nd is optional) and you're done! Just upload it to your site of choice.

Source: [YouTube, Ambisonics, and VR](https://www.brucewiggins.co.uk/?p=666)

Comment: Hi there! I was looking for a way to transform Blender generated audio into Spatial Audio and this is one of the few adices I found, however it's been a while and I wanted to know if it's still the best/easiest method to follow.
If so where can I find step by step instructions? I've never used reaper and don't know where to start...